# The import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to resolve this from sometime now.But Still i didn't get it solved.I just downloaded a spring project form spring.io and just imported it as a Maven project to Eclipse IDE.After that i get this above mentioned error.

**The import org.springframework.test.context.junit4 cannot be resolved**

I have attached my code below.Together with the full pom.xml content.

```
package com.Ticket.Booking.TicketBooking;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;//I got the error in this line

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)//Also in this line too.
@SpringBootTest
public class TicketBookingApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Here's my pom.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.Ticket.Booking</groupId>
<artifactId>Ticket-Booking</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Ticket-Booking</name>
<description>Project For Book Movie Tickets Online.</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.It's very much important for me as a student.

Answer (score 12):

It could be the scope, which is set to `test`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please make sure that the class that has the `SpringRunner` is in your `/src/test/java` folder.

Comment: I have already put the scope as test in the above code.Also the Class which i used SpringRunner is in /src/test/java folder.But still i get the same error as before.

Comment: actually I had the same problem and by moving the class to test folder it got fixed. @HKhan maybe you need to right click on your project and then go to maven and then click on Update Project. and the clean your project.

Comment: This fixed for me.. ESPECIALLY that last `*/java/` folder, which is what I was missing.

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I had the latest eclipse and also the latest junit 4.12 jar but still I use to get this problem. I finally fixed it. Follow these steps:

1. Close your maven project created in eclipse and close eclipse or STS tool.
2. Go to Maven repository:

> C:\Users\.m2\repository\org\springframework\

and delete everything inside springframework folder.

3. Now open eclipse/STS tool and then open your project.
4. The project will build automatically and the error disappears.
5. If it doesn't then

> right click on project -> Maven -> Update Project.. -> check the Force
>   Update and click OK

Comment: Perfect, this fixed a bunch of my errors. Although I did go straight to just forcing the update. Now I am unit and integration testing like a pro, semi-pro? :)

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I think a dependency is missing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Should not import springframework dependencies with spring boot, nor should you override the versions if you do. Starters are prefered when possible.

Comment: This worked fine.That error was flew away.But now i can't clean compile the package.It says that there's test failures.

Comment: @HKhan if this was required there is something wrong with your project setup or dependencies that have not downloaded correctly in the .m2 repo. This is not required to to get the spring runner in a spring boot application and it is not recommended.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe i deleted the whole .m2 repo and re added it.So now it's working as it should work.Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your using a BUILD-SNAPSHOT?

In your pom.xml you have

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

use version

```
<version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
```

or another RELEASE version.

Don't override library version unless is really necessary.